# Duplicate question title on the post feedback page

Tags: bug, design, 10k-tools

On the [post feedback tab of the 10k moderator tools page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback/underrated?filter=all) if you press the "show full question" link, this will lead to duplicating the question title:

> [image]